# Как изменить кол-во символов в брутфорсе (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, password

У меня есть кода с гитхаба:

```
import itertools
import string
import pyautogui as pag
import time

def bruteforce_attack():
    chars = string.printable.strip()
    for length in range(1, 10):
        for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=length):
            pag.click(x=325,y=580)
            pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
            guess = ''.join(guess)
            pag.write(guess, interval = 0)
            pag.click(x=480,y=580)

bruteforce_attack()
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы брутфорс начинался не с "1 2 3 4 5... aaa bbb ccc", а сразу с 9 символов "000000000 000000001 000000002... aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaab и т.д."? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что никто еще не ответил, вот решение:

```
import itertools
import string
import pyautogui as pag
import time

def bruteforce_attack():
    chars = string.printable.strip()
    for length in range(1, 10):
        for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=9):
            pag.click(x=325,y=580)
            pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
            guess = ''.join(guess)
            pag.write(guess, interval = 0)
            pag.click(x=480,y=580)

bruteforce_attack()
```

Comment: И в итоге вы тратите время на перебор одних и тех же значений по десять раз непонятно зачем. Перед работой с кодом стоило бы сперва изучить какие-нибудь основы...

Comment: А никто не ответил во-первых потому что ночь была, большинство ночью спит. А во-вторых с вредоносным кодом помогать особенного желания нет. Ну а так да, просто один цикл лишний тогда.

Comment: @andreymal я поэтому и задал вопрос потому, что не понимал особо этого кода, мне нужно было просто по быстрому сделать брутфорсер на основе чужого кода

Comment: @CrazyElf ну почему же сразу вредоносный? У меня идеи закончились, решил что нибудь на автоматизацию сделать